# Scalability Setting on two CD servers

Tags: publishing, publishing-targets

We have set up one CM and two CD nodes( CD1 & CD2 ). After publishing cache not gets cleared on CD1 node but on CD2 it's working fine i.e. we can see published content immediately on CD2 but for CD1 I have to clear cache going through /admin/cache.aspx page.

I have gone through some articles and find out below which I'm planning to implement on production but just wanted to confirm if caching issue on CD1 will be really fixed.
We have same connection string on CM and CD server.

**CM node**

```
<setting name="InstanceName">
   <patch:attribute name="value">abc12efdcms01</patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
   <patch:attribute name="value">abc12efdcms01</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

where abc12efdcms01 is CM node machine name

**CD1 node**

```
<setting name="InstanceName">
   <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
   <patch:attribute name="value">abc12efdcms01</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

**CD2 node**

```
<setting name="InstanceName">
   <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
   <patch:attribute name="value">abc12efdcms01</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

Is this correct settings on both node.

In IIS the name of website in CMS Website. Should I put `abc12efdcms01-CMS Website` OR the current one is fine.

We already have below settings:

```
<setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true">

<eventQueue>
  <!-- Time between checking the queue for newly queued events. If new events are found they will be raised. -->
  <processingInterval>00:00:02</processingInterval>
</eventQueue>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the InstanceName to unique values on your CDs, such as abc12efdcms01-cd1 and abc12efdcms01-cd2

The servers are looking at that value to see if it has already completed the actions in the queue.  With both servers set to the same name, the second one is thinking it has already completed the task.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server#_Changes_to_configuration_1

We use a patch file in a zzz folder that has a different value for each server.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="InstanceName">
        <patch:attribute name="value">CD1</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As per my understanding on CD( CD1 & CD2 ) nodes if we don't put any value in InstanceName then system will automatically consider value to MachineName+IIS name so that's why I didn't set any InstanceName for CD nodes but Publishing.PublishingInstance value is must
Am I correct?

Comment: I've always explicitly set it, but I do see an article where someone says what you're saying is true.  Any differences in the configs between the two servers, could you be missing a call to a publish end event?  Anything showing up in the publishing logs on CD2?

Comment: No difference in config basically we have two folder in VS project solution says CM & CD which keep env. specific config files. On each production deployment I delete App_Config folder and paste on both CD nodes...
Not sure If I'm missing publish end event...didn't find anything in CD2 log files...

Comment: It would be listening for publish:end:remote but if the configs on both of your CDs are the same and it is working one one and not the other...

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean but I do have publish:end and publish:end:remote event already configured

Comment: So How can I make configs different from each other to fix this issue

Comment: Sorry, things got busy.  We use a patch file that's specific to each server in a zzz folder.  If this doesn't work you might try Slack to see if you can get some interactive assistance.

Comment: The patch should do the trick. At my company we use Octopus Deploy and specify the value using the Octopus Substitute Variables feature.

Comment: actually I added x as an suffix in file name --> xScalabilitySettings.config file....Is that fine?

Comment: I just notice that interval is not set in following config changes 
<!--  Agent to clear the HTML cache periodically  -->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.HtmlCacheClearAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00"/>
By setting some value does solve this caching issue